Changing the default sort order id for Sybase ASE
I am setting up a Sybase ASE server through the datagrip/sybase image at Docker hub.
Im having so much pain trying to change the sort order. Basically what I need is for querying columns and tables to be case insensitive, i.e:
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
SELECT * from mytable 

should both work and return the same.
I am trying to change the sort order like this:
sp_configure 'default character set id', 52
But I get the error message:

Cannot reconfigure server to use sort order ID 52, because the row for its underlying character set (ID 1) does not exist in syscharsets.

I do not understand how I am supposed to bring this charset into my db. I though this row in my syscharsets would mean I have this sort order available:
{
"select * from master..syscharsets\norder by type": [
    {
        "type" : 2003,
        "id" : 52,
        "csid" : 190,
        "status" : 0,
        "name" : "nocase",
        "description" : "General-purpose case-insensitive dictionary ordering",
        "definition" : null,
        "sortfile" : null
    }
]}

Wondering if anyone knows anything about how to solve my problem? Either finding out how to set the sort order or using a different approach. It is just a local db so there is no worrying about rights or corrupted data.

There are 2 different configuration settings of interest:

default character set id - modifies the dataserver's default character set
default sortorder id - modifies the dataserver's default sort order

OP should try the following:
-- change this:

sp_configure 'default character set id', 52
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

-- to this:

sp_configure 'default sortorder id', 52
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The error message is a bit misleading since it mentions both 'character set' and 'sort order'.  This is due to the fact that changing either config runs additional checks to verify a valid combo of the default character set and sort order.  In OP's case 52 is an invalid character set id so the queries (used to perform the validation checks) don't generate the expected results hence the error message (ie, garbage in => garbage out).  To make more sense of what's going on OP can review the source code for sp_configure to see how the validation checks are performed.
NOTE: changing the default character set and/or default sort order should be performed right after the dataserver has been created and before any user data is added to a database as indexes will need to be rebuilt (much easier/faster with the relatively small system tables; much more complicated with large volumes of user data)
If the change in configuration name (replace default character set id with default sortorder id) does not address the issue then consider updating the question with the latest code changes, the new error message(s), and the output from running the following:
-- only need to see the last section - Sort Order Description - of the following:

sp_helpsort
go

print "###### character sets"
go

select id,name as charset
from   master..syscharsets
where  type < 2000
order by id
go

print "###### sort orders"
go

select s.id,c.name as 'charset',s.name as sortord
from   master..syscharsets s
left
join   master..syscharsets c
on     s.csid = c.id
and    c.type < 2000
and    s.type >= 2000
order by s.id,c.name
go

